# Run a .vbs script that connects to Teradata with no timeout

Tags: vba, odbc, teradata

Is there ANY way to run a .vbs file with a connection with a larger timeout?

**Background:**

I'm using Excel VBA to upload data to Teradata.  It's relatively easy to create an insert statement and then execute it with rs.Execute().

However, for around 80k rows, this takes about an hour to run.  I thought of two possible speedups.

1) Send multiple rows (say, 500) to the rs.Execute() at a time, separated by semicolons, and let Teradata insert them in parallel.

2) Send multiple insert requests at a time without waiting for the 1st one to finish.  This is difficult in VBA, since there's no support for multithreading and rs.Execute is blocking.  So to get around this, I created .vbs files which just contain this:

```
Dim rs
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
constr = "Driver={Teradata};commandTimeout=0;DBCNAME=xx;UID=xx;PWD=xx;"
rs.Open "insert statement1;insert statement2;", constr, adOpenForwardOnly
```

And I spin off a bunch of those.  however, if i send too much data at once, it times out (Teradata has a 30 second timeout for queries run this way.  "commandTimeout" doesn't appear to have any effect whether I set it to 0 or 1200 or whatever.  I can't find an appropriate size packet to insert since the load on Teradata keeps changing with use throughout the day.  Sometimes 500 at a time works fine and sometimes only 15 stays under the 30s timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The default for commandTimeout is zero, which indicates infinite :-)

Are you sure it's a timeout and not a rollback due to a deadlock? When you got multiple session you might be forced to use single row inserts (based on your data).

I don't know if this is possible in VBA, but using ODBC you can send data much more efficient using [Parameter Arrays](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/Connectivity/B035_2509_082K/2509ch06.08.57.html)

Comment: The default is 30s, which must be set by my DB admins.  I'm sure it's a time out because i get a popup window for each one saying the query has timed out.  I'm not forced to used single row inserts, since some of the time 5 can insert within 30s and sometimes 500 rows work just fine within 30s, depending on the DB load.

Comment: Also, I have googled around, and I can't find any examples of using parameter arrays.  The link you attached explains them somewhat, but I'm still lost.  How can I insert two rows at a time to Teradata by using a parameter array?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in VBA, maybe it's not possible at all. But if it's possible your load might be at least 10 to 50 times faster compared to single row inserts. Submitting multiple Inserts is a bit similar, but there's much more overhead on the server side.

Comment: Regarding the timeout, it's not set by the DBA, because there's no timeout on Teradata side. You might ask your DBA if Teradata's query log is enabled for your user/session and he should check the actual errors.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of using a parameter array in any language?  Is it a SQL construct?

Comment: It's no SQL, it's at the client side, see http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/speed-up-your-jdbcodbc-applications